# Removing NULL objects from an environment

Tags: r, quantmod

I have an environment of objects that are either xts or `NULL`. I would like to remove all the `NULL` from the environment. Is there a function I can use with `eapply` to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rm(
  list=names(
    which(
      sapply(globalenv(),is.null) # or .GlobalEnv
      )
    )
  )
```

If it's not the global environment, you can use the `envir` switch in `rm` and wrap the environment name in `getenv()` in the `sapply` call

Comment: `globalenv()` would be better (less obscure).

Comment: @GavinSimpson Hrmmm, why would you say using .GlobalEnv is obscure?

Comment: It is the **actual** global envioronmnent and the `.` in the name means it is hidden or intended to be hidden from normal view. `globalenv()` is the accessor function.

Comment: Interesting. Strange that it doesn't work that way in practice.

Comment: I mean that it seems to act in a manner that's almost interchangeable with `globalenv()`.

Comment: Yes, that is my point. `.GlobalEnv` is the object that *is* the global environment, the actual thing. `globalenv()` returns this. It's a bit like `mod$coefficients` and coef(mod)` both give you what you want but it is better to access via the accessor function than directly.

Comment: You're going to laugh but I also commonly use `$coefficients`. Hopeless. lol